# Converting Web app into Desktop app with Electron

Tags: electron

Hey i am web developer and i wanted to make app for desktop. I discovered program named Electron i downloaded it from this page: electron.atom.io

Next I created files that are needed for running this app:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello World!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    We are using node <script>document.write(process.versions.node)</script>,
    Chrome <script>document.write(process.versions.chrome)</script>,
    and Electron <script>document.write(process.versions.electron)</script>.
  </body>
</html>
```

Then main.js:

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
const path = require('path')
const url = require('url')

// Keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window will
// be closed automatically when the JavaScript object is garbage collected.
let win

function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  win = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600})

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  win.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
    protocol: 'file:',
    slashes: true
  }))

  // Open the DevTools.
  win.webContents.openDevTools()

  // Emitted when the window is closed.
  win.on('closed', () => {
    // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
    // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
    // when you should delete the corresponding element.
    win = null
  })
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on('ready', createWindow)

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  // On macOS it is common for applications and their menu bar
  // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('activate', () => {
  // On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  if (win === null) {
    createWindow()
  }
})

// In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
// code. You can also put them in separate files and require them here.
```

and package.json:

```
{
  "name"    : "Test-App",
  "version" : "0.1.0",
  "main"    : "main.js"
}
```

Now when i type in CMD

> Electron .

i get the error

> 'electron' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Is there any way to run this program from app installed without CMD or How can i fix this?

Comment: Do you have electron installed globally? `npm install -g electron`

Comment: I installed electron with installer not with npm @devilfart

Comment: @S.Mi there is no installer for Electron, it's distributed and installed via NPM. You probably downloaded and installed the Electron API Demos app which contains demos of Electron APIs.

Comment: Yeah that is the name of Electron i downloaded but how can i install it by npm? @Vadim Macagon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to stackoverflow!

The package you installed is a demo package that is meant to demonstrate the different features Electron offers to developers. It is not suitable for your needs right now.

What you need instead is, as devilfart and Vadim pointed out, a global installation of the Electron runtime. This can be achieved by starting a command line with administrative rights and entering the following command:

`npm install -g electron`

This will install the Electron runtime as a global package inside your base node_modules directory and enable the use of the `electron` command.